# How to change phone hardware configuration as per requirement of Android Nougat?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, micromax

I am using Micromax android one. Till now my phone upgraded from 4.4.4 (KitKat) to 6.0.1(Marshmallow). But since my hardware configuration was getting low to get ready for N, How can I change my hardware configuration? I also want to know what hardware configuration required for Android Nougat.

Comment: How to change? Buy a new device. What is required? Vulkan support and OpenGL 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite people saying certain levels of hardware are *required* for Android version bla.bla.bla, they're not. Look how older phones like HD2, Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 received Nougat treatment - it might not be smooth, but in the latter 2 cases are definitely usable.

The thing you'll be missing without official support is the proprietary drivers, which third-party devs won't be able to provide. If your processor is older (e.g. Snapdragon 800/801), you'll also miss out on newer features like Vulkan. But fret not, as Android still reserves a bit of backwards compatibility - devs can always work it so that it runs on legacy drivers and APIs.

As an Android One device you shouldn't be worried much - just wait for N-based custom ROMs to drop.

Comment: Ohh you mean to say that it's not much hardware dependant. Only I need is Big RAM & Good processor already inbuilt. Is there any official page for this requirement.

Comment: @iO.S-C. Certainly not, as demonstrated in the countless examples that have popped up since Nougat release (one more example: Xperia M). Also, since Nougat isn't as big a revision as Lollipop versus KitKat, it likely won't introduce much lag either - rest assured that your phone would work alright for another year (if the custom ROMs come, that is).

Comment: Nice, thanks for all this information. It help me  to understood. I heard about one more thing, that they are removing background services like iOS. Is it true?

Comment: @iO.S-C. That's something I haven't heard of. Given how heavily Android depends on multitasking (non-tombstone) both in development and in real world use, I'd say no. That's also not likely to happen within the timeframe of Nougat, so your phone won't be affected either.

Comment: As I am using Android One I am bit sure that I'll get Nougat on my device, Only thing is that I have to make my space free. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using a first-gen Andriod one device.
Google has said in an official statement that'll they will **not** be updated to Nougat.

Your next best option is to try out a custom rom like Cyanogenmod 14 for your device.

PS: Do this only if you're confident that you will not brick your device.